# Selecting and Appending a <li> based on `data-id`

Tags: javascript, jquery

The application which I have build in Laravel could enable the user to edit certain models etc. On the create event, a `jstree` is generated to appoint specific data features to variables. Now, the `jstree` has to be adjusted but the variables which were already stored need to be visualized again! This way, the user would have to re-enter all the data.

On the selection of a `jstree` node, the following code is executed:

```
$(document).on('submit','form:not(.secret)',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var id      = $('.modal-body input[type=hidden]').val();
    console.log(id);

    var li = $('li[id='+id+']');

    var field   = li.data('id');
    console.log(field);

    var text    = li.text();
    console.log(text);

    var value = $('.modal-body select').val();
    console.log(value);

    $("#html1").jstree('rename_node', '#'+id, text+' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span> '+value);
    $("#html1").jstree(true).set_icon('#'+id, "glyphicon glyphicon-check");

    $('form.secret').append('<input type="hidden" name="'+field+'" value="'+value+'"/>');

  });
```

[image]

Now, I need to pass an array of already selected variables. The JSON is formated like:

```
{"KnSubject":{"Element":{"Fields":{"StId":"{{Omschrijving}}","Da":"{{Omschrijving}}","SaId":"{{Omschrijving}}"}},"Objects":[]}}
```

So, the ID is not stored. But when looking through the console. The key value is partially called in the `data-id` attribute.
[image]

The code which I have now loops through these keys, but now I need to append the `jstree` node based on the partial key which is called. Could someone help me with this?

The which i have now:

```
@foreach ($text_data as $value)
    $("#html1").jstree('rename_node', '#'+id, text+' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span> '+value);
    $("#html1").jstree(true).set_icon('#'+id, "glyphicon glyphicon-check");
    $('form.secret').append('<input type="hidden" name="'+field+'" value="'+value+'"/>');
@endforeach
```